# How to maximize the function

Tags: geometry, derivatives, triangles

I have a triangle $T=ABC$. I want to calculate $\max (a-b)$, where the the angle  $ABC = \beta$, and $|AB|=c$ is fixed (pre-known). My guess is $c\times\cos (\beta)$, but I want to prove it.

Let $A$,$B$,$C$ denote the vertices of $T$, and $|AB|=c$,$|AC|=b$, and $|BC|=a$.

[image]

Comment: Your guess $a \times \cos \beta$ contains $a$ in it. It should only contain constants ($c$ and $\beta$).

Comment: Yes, You are true, it is $c\times\cos(\beta)$

Comment: Hint: Use cosine formula to write $b$ in terms of $a$, $c$, $\beta$.

Comment: I did it, but strangely, the value of the variable (a) disappears during calculation!

Comment: ?? How would that be??

Comment: $f(a)=a-b=a-\sqrt(a^2+c^2-2 a c \cos(\beta))$. Then, Let $d(f)/d(a)=0$. But I cannot find $a$ from the equation!!

Comment: Good! Did you compute $df/da$ and found that it is always positive?

Comment: What do you mean. Please make more details if possible. I cannot describe why $a$ disappears!

Comment: OK let me write down a solution.....

Comment: Yes. I am eager to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the cosine formula

$$b^2 = a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos \beta \Rightarrow b = \sqrt{a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos \beta}\ .$$

Write $f(a) = a-b = a-  \sqrt{a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos \beta}$, then

$$f'(a) = 1- \frac{a-c\cos\beta}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos \beta}}\ .$$

As $a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos \beta = (a-c\cos\beta)^2 - c^2 \cos^2\beta + c^2 = (a-c\cos\beta)^2 + c^2 \sin^2\beta$, we see that

$$\bigg|\frac{a-c\cos\beta}{\sqrt{a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos \beta}} \bigg|\leq 1$$

and $f'(a)>0$ for all $a$. This means $f$ is increasing. So the maximum value of $f$ is never attained (that is the reason you cannot find $a$), but we can still find out the upper bound of $f$ by calculating

$$\lim_{a\to +\infty} f(a) = \lim_{a\to +\infty} \big(a-  \sqrt{a^2 + c^2 - 2ac\cos \beta}\big) = c\cos\beta \ \ \text{(How?)}\ .$$

Thus your guess is almost correct: the value $c\cos\beta$ can never be attained, but is the smallest upper bound of $a-b$.